# PIC24F - Possible for data values to persist, even after the PIC is powered off?

Tags: memory-management, persistence, pic, persistent-storage

I have a question regarding the persistence (storage) of data values in a PIC24F, even after the PIC has been turned off.

I have read through the datasheet(s), but am confused regarding the difference of the EEPROM and Flash memory.

For example, say I have a variable "x", is there a way for the value of "x" to persist even after the PIC has been shut off?  I know programs can persist in the flash memory so long as the code is compiled in Stand Alone Operation (COE_OFF).  However, I am specifically wondering about data values.

If I make the program memory and the memory for the data value non-volatile, will it persist even when the power is off?

Do I need to declare the value as "static", example: static int x; ?

Or am I wrong and there isn't any way for a data value to persist even after the power has been turned off?

Thanks for the help and clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

You must write to flash in pages, using the TBLWTL and TBLWTH instructions, as you have read in the datasheet for your device. This is typically for updating your software through a bootloader, and it does not sound like this is what you are after.

To access the EEPROM you can do it in smaller units, and there are compiler convenience macros for declaring where in the memory map a variable should live. You can specify that the variable lives in EEPROM and the compiler will generate instructions for accessing and updating that for you. You can also use the compiler intrinsics or the TBL instructions for reading it directly.

The declaration will probably look something like:

```
unsigned __attribute__((space(eedata), aligned(2)) my_eeprom_variable;
```

Look at the generated assembler to see what the compiler does when you access the variable.

Declaring a variable `static` only has traditional C semantics; it controls the scope of the variable and the initialisation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Contents of registers and RAM variables are lost when power is turned off.  Flash and EEPROM are both persistent.  Flash can only be erased in large blocks - 128K and up depending on the type that you have.  EEPROM words can be individually read or written.  If you have EEPROM, that's your best bet for saving a small amount of data.  Usually you have to read and write EEPROM serially.

Comment: A PIC24 will have up to 128k of flash in the whole device, not a single page. The page size is 1.5kBytes (8 rows of 64 instructions, three bytes each).

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the responses!

After some other suggestions I read through the MPLAB C30 Compiler datasheet again, and found the "persistent" attribute.

Per the datasheet:

"The persistent attribute specifies that the variable should not be initialized or cleared at startup. A variable with the persistent attribute could be used to store state information that will remain valid after a device reset."

I'm going to try using this to see if it will work.